# Appscript to extract notes only from Google Slides into a Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Google Slides can only "print" notes with the slides included. I would like to extract all notes (and their formatting) into a blank Google Doc without the slide picture.

tried converting to Powerpoint but it did not help. Need an Appscript

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to get the notes and place them in a new Document.  But that as far as I'm going to go.  I would suggest you study the reference links I've provided so you can start developing scripts on your own.

**Code.gs**

```
function getNotes() {
  try {
    let presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
    let slides = presentation.getSlides();
    let doc = DocumentApp.create("Slide Notes");
    let body = doc.getBody();
    slides.forEach( slide => {
        let notesPage = slide.getNotesPage();
        let shapes = notesPage.getShapes();
        shapes.forEach( shape => {
            if( shape.getShapeType() === SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX ) {
              body.appendParagraph(shape.getText().asString());
            }
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**References**

- [SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app)
- [Slide.getNotesPage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getNotesPage())
- [Shape.getShapeType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#getShapeType())
- [DocumentApp.create()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#create(String))
- [Document.getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getBody())
- [Body.appendParagraph()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendParagraph(String))

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the first part. Now I just need for it to make a blank document with the notes sections.

Comment: I need something that captures all of the formatting and not just the text.

Comment: The code works great but it make it all as one big paragraph. This does not allow me to delete blank lines/paragraphs